# BitNami Apache Passenger start Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, bitnami

I'm try to ran web server Apache with Passenger After passenger-install-apache2-module i have this error:

```
WARNING: Apache doesn't seem to be compiled with the 'prefork' or 'worker' MPM

Passenger has only been tested on Apache with the 'prefork' and the 'worker'
MPM. Your Apache installation is compiled with the '' MPM. We recommend
you to abort this installer and to recompile Apache with either the 'prefork'
or the 'worker' MPM.

Press Ctrl-C to abort this installer (recommended).
Press Enter if you want to continue with installation anyway.


--------------------------------------------
Compiling and installing Apache 2 module...
cd /home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2
/home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/ruby/bin/ruby /home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/ruby/bin/rake apache2:clean apache2 RELEASE=yes
# /home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/ruby/bin/ruby /home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/ruby/bin/rake apache2:clean apache2 RELEASE=yes
/home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb:33: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
rm -rf ext/common/libboost_oxt.a ext/common/libboost_oxt
rm -rf ext/common/libpassenger_common.a ext/common/libpassenger_common
rm -f agents/PassengerWatchdog agents/PassengerLoggingAgent
rm -rf ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt.a ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt
rm -rf ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common.a ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common
rm -rf ext/apache2/Configuration.o ext/apache2/Bucket.o ext/apache2/Hooks.o ext/apache2/mod_passenger.o ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so agents/PassengerHelperAgent
mkdir -p ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common
g++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DLINUX=2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.o -c ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp
rm -rf ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common.a
ar cru ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common.a ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.o
ranlib ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common.a
mkdir -p ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt
g++ -Iext -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DLINUX=2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt/aggregate.o -c ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt/aggregate.cpp
In file included from ext/boost/src/pthread/thread.cpp:27:0,
                 from ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt/aggregate.cpp:6:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function ‘void {anonymous}::to_time(int, boost::xtime&)’:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:22:9: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function ‘void {anonymous}::to_timespec_duration(const boost::xtime&, timespec&)’:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:59:9: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function ‘void {anonymous}::to_duration(boost::xtime, int&)’:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:90:9: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function ‘void {anonymous}::to_microduration(boost::xtime, int&)’:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:112:9: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
mkdir -p ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt
rm -rf ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt.a
ar cru ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt.a ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt/aggregate.o
ranlib ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt.a
gcc -Iext -Iext/common -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DLINUX=2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/apache2/mod_passenger.o -c ext/apache2/mod_passenger.c
g++ -Iext -Iext/common -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DLINUX=2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/apache2/Configuration.o -c ext/apache2/Configuration.cpp
g++ -Iext -Iext/common -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DLINUX=2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/apache2/Bucket.o -c ext/apache2/Bucket.cpp
g++ -Iext -Iext/common -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DLINUX=2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/apache2/Hooks.o -c ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp
g++ -shared ext/apache2/Configuration.o ext/apache2/Bucket.o ext/apache2/Hooks.o ext/apache2/mod_passenger.o -fPIC -o ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -Wno-attributes -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DLINUX=2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/xmltok -pthread -I/usr/include/apache2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common.a ext/apache2/module_libboost_oxt.a -fPIC -L/usr/lib -lapr-1 -L/usr/lib -laprutil-1 -lpthread  
mkdir -p ext/common/libpassenger_common
g++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/common/libpassenger_common/aggregate.o -c ext/common/libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp
rm -rf ext/common/libpassenger_common.a
ar cru ext/common/libpassenger_common.a ext/common/libpassenger_common/aggregate.o
ranlib ext/common/libpassenger_common.a
mkdir -p ext/common/libboost_oxt
g++ -Iext  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -o ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.o -c ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.cpp
In file included from ext/boost/src/pthread/thread.cpp:27:0,
                 from ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.cpp:6:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function ‘void {anonymous}::to_time(int, boost::xtime&)’:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:22:9: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function ‘void {anonymous}::to_timespec_duration(const boost::xtime&, timespec&)’:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:59:9: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function ‘void {anonymous}::to_duration(boost::xtime, int&)’:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:90:9: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl: In function ‘void {anonymous}::to_microduration(boost::xtime, int&)’:
ext/boost/src/pthread/timeconv.inl:112:9: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
mkdir -p ext/common/libboost_oxt
rm -rf ext/common/libboost_oxt.a
ar cru ext/common/libboost_oxt.a ext/common/libboost_oxt/aggregate.o
ranlib ext/common/libboost_oxt.a
g++ ext/apache2/HelperAgent.cpp -o agents/apache2/PassengerHelperAgent -Iext -Iext/common -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS ext/common/libpassenger_common.a ext/common/libboost_oxt.a -lpthread -rdynamic 
g++ ext/common/Watchdog.cpp -o agents/PassengerWatchdog -Iext -Iext/common -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS ext/common/libpassenger_common.a ext/common/libboost_oxt.a -lpthread -rdynamic 
ext/common/Watchdog.cpp: In function ‘void cleanupAgentsInBackground(std::vector<AgentWatcher*>&)’:
ext/common/Watchdog.cpp:804:6: warning: variable ‘e’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
g++ ext/common/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp -o agents/PassengerLoggingAgent -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -I/home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/common/include -DHAS_CURL_EASY_RESET  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -DHAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS ext/common/libpassenger_common.a ext/common/libboost_oxt.a ext/libev/.libs/libev.a -L/home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/common/lib -lcurl -lz -lpthread -rdynamic 
In file included from ext/common/LoggingAgent/../EventedMessageServer.h:31:0,
                 from ext/common/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:48,
                 from ext/common/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:43:
ext/common/LoggingAgent/../EventedServer.h: In member function ‘void Passenger::EventedServer::freeAllClients()’:
ext/common/LoggingAgent/../EventedServer.h:145:23: warning: variable ‘end’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
In file included from ext/common/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:43:0:
ext/common/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h: In member function ‘void Passenger::LoggingServer::LogFile::notifyChanges()’:
ext/common/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:167:38: warning: variable ‘end’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o: In function `~bad_day_of_month':
/home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_day.hpp:20: undefined reference to `std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o: In function `std::list<oxt::thread_registration*, std::allocator<oxt::thread_registration*> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<oxt::thread_registration*>, oxt::thread_registration* const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1516: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o: In function `std::list<oxt::thread_registration*, std::allocator<oxt::thread_registration*> >::_M_erase(std::_List_iterator<oxt::thread_registration*>)':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1532: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o: In function `std::list<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1516: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o: In function `std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::RemoteSender::Server>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::RemoteSender::Server> > >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::RemoteSender::Server> >, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::RemoteSender::Server> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1516: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o: In function `std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::RemoteSender::Server>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::RemoteSender::Server> > >::_M_erase(std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::RemoteSender::Server> >)':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1532: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o: In function `std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::LoggingServer::LogSink>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::LoggingServer::LogSink> > >::_M_erase(std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::LoggingServer::LogSink> >)':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1532: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o: In function `std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::LoggingServer::LogSink>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::LoggingServer::LogSink> > >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::LoggingServer::LogSink> >, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::LoggingServer::LogSink> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1516: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o: In function `~bad_year':
/home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_year.hpp:20: undefined reference to `std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o: In function `~bad_month':
/home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp:44: undefined reference to `std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_10bad_alloc_EEE[vtable for boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::bad_alloc_>]+0x28): undefined reference to `std::bad_alloc::what() const'
/tmp/ccXtITl2.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10bad_alloc_E[vtable for boost::exception_detail::bad_alloc_]+0x20): undefined reference to `std::bad_alloc::what() const'
ext/common/libpassenger_common.a(aggregate.o): In function `std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::CachedFileStat::Entry>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::CachedFileStat::Entry> > >::_M_erase(std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::CachedFileStat::Entry> >)':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1532: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
ext/common/libpassenger_common.a(aggregate.o): In function `std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::CachedFileStat::Entry>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::CachedFileStat::Entry> > >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::CachedFileStat::Entry> >, boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::CachedFileStat::Entry> const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1516: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
ext/common/libboost_oxt.a(aggregate.o): In function `std::list<oxt::trace_point*, std::allocator<oxt::trace_point*> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<oxt::trace_point*>, oxt::trace_point* const&)':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_list.h:1516: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [g++ ext/common/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp -o ag...]

Tasks: TOP => apache2 => agents/PassengerLoggingAgent
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

--------------------------------------------
```

It looks like something went wrong

Please read our Users guide for troubleshooting tips:

/home/sergey/rubystack-1.9.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/doc/Users guide Apache.html

If that doesn't help, please use our support facilities at:

http://www.modrails.com/

```
We'll do our best to help you.
```

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitNami RubyStack already ships the Passenger module so it is not necessary to add it.

(Note: This question was also posted in BitNami but I thought it was convenient to also include here a reponse)